# How can I create a function that sorts the string according to the integer(1-9) in that string?

Tags: javascript

Hi stackoverflow community! I am stuck again on a javascript problem. Can someone please advise?

The function `order` is supposed to take a string like  `"is2 Thi1s T4est 3a"` as an input and will return as `"Thi1s is2 3a T4est"`. With each word having an integer (1-9), I am supposed to sort that string. For some reason my code does not sort the words accordingly and still returns it as `'is2 Thi1s T4est 3a'`

Here is my code:

```
function order(words){
  let newStr = words.split(" ").sort(function(x,y){
    return parseInt(x) - parseInt(y);
  }).join(" ");
  return newStr;
};
```

Comment: try `parseInt(x.replace(/[\D]+/g, ''))` and same for `y`

Comment: ooo i see removing all the characters and leaving the integers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parseInt` won't work as it will just return `NaN`.

You can [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) on the number with regex and then sort with that.

```js
const str = 'is2 Thi1s T4est 3a';
const regex = /\d/;
const arr = str.split(' ');

arr.sort((a, b) => {
  return a.match(regex) - b.match(regex);
});

console.log(arr.join(' '));
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this very simple approach, using variables, maybe the other solutions are better, but I'm gonna add this anyway, in case it's needed

```js
function order(words){
  let newStr = words.split(" ").sort(function(x,y){
    let n1, n2
    x.split('').forEach((el) => {
      if(!isNaN(el))
        n1 = el
    })
    
    y.split('').forEach((el) => {
      if(!isNaN(el))
        n2 = el
    })

    if(n1 < n2)
      return -1;
    if(n1 > n2)
      return 1;
    return 0;
  })
  return newStr;
};

console.log(order('is2 Thi1s T4est 3a'))
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  
</body>
</html>
```